# Horizontal UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout displaying section headers over item cells

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

I am attempting to use UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout to create this design:

[image: UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout desired layout]

The intention here is for the collection view to scroll horizontally, with the items also scrolling vertically when they overflow using NSCollectionLayoutSection's `orthogonalScrollingBehavior` property.

This is the layout I have right now:

```
private lazy var collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout = {
    let sectionWidth: CGFloat = 256.0

    let layoutItemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .estimated(50.0))
    let layoutItem = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: layoutItemSize)

    let layoutGroupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .absolute(sectionWidth), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0))
    let layoutGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.vertical(layoutSize: layoutGroupSize, subitems: [layoutItem])
    layoutGroup.interItemSpacing = .fixed(8.0)

    let layoutSectionHeaderItemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .absolute(sectionWidth), heightDimension: .absolute(150.0))
    let layoutSectionHeaderItem = NSCollectionLayoutBoundarySupplementaryItem(layoutSize: layoutSectionHeaderItemSize, elementKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, alignment: .top)

    let layoutSection = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: layoutGroup)
    layoutSection.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 24.0, leading: 24.0, bottom: 24.0, trailing: 24.0)
    layoutSection.boundarySupplementaryItems = [layoutSectionHeaderItem]
    layoutSection.interGroupSpacing = 8.0

    let layoutConfiguration = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayoutConfiguration()
    layoutConfiguration.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    layoutConfiguration.interSectionSpacing = 16.0

    return UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(section: layoutSection, configuration: layoutConfiguration)
}()
```

The result is:

[image: UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout actual layout]

Any ideas as to where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 months later and no direct solutions to this one (either here, nor via bug report from Apple). So to get the design I was after I ended up reconfiguring the view structure.

In short, to get vertically-scrolling columns with a pinned header within a horizontally-scrolling collection view I placed a table view in the collection view cell, with the header elements above it, all in a stack view.

I kept the UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout on the collection view, which has been simplified:

```
private lazy var collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout = {
    let layoutItemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0))
    let layoutItem = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: layoutItemSize)
    
    let fractionalWidth: CGFloat = (Device.current.isPad) ? 0.5 : 1.0
    let layoutGroupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(fractionalWidth), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0))
    let layoutGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.vertical(layoutSize: layoutGroupSize, subitems: [layoutItem])
    let layoutSection = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: layoutGroup)
    
    let layoutConfiguration = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayoutConfiguration()
    layoutConfiguration.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    
    return UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(section: layoutSection, configuration: layoutConfiguration)
}()
```